# Apply classes or styles to JS Proxy Objects

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Using Nuxt 3 I have a v-for with a ref assigned:

```
<div v-for="item in content" ref="theItems" />
```

then I try to loop with a for of:

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  content: Array
})

const theItems = ref()

onMounted(() => {
  for (const item of theItems.value) {
    console.log(item)
  }
})
</script>
```

on the console I get:

```
Proxy(Object) {__v_skip: true}
Proxy(Object) {__v_skip: true}
Proxy(Object) {__v_skip: true}
```

and I don't seem to be able to do anything with those Proxy Objects. What is the way to be able to manipulate the divs generated via v-for?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem on an online tool? I tested on my local and it shows the raw div